# writerows output to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am currently printing data from a rest api.  It is able to print fine, but I want to save the output to a column on a csv.  I get the error

```
TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable
```

Here is my code:

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
    for issue in jira.search_issues('project in (FITQA, UXSCIENCE, '
        'FITSW, FIT) AND status = Resolved AND environment ~ "TC*" '
        'ORDER BY created DESC', maxResults=100):
            a = issue.fields.priority
            print a
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(a)
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(a)`? `print(type(a))`? What about `writer.writerow(a)` instead of `writer.writerows(a)`?

Comment: writer.writerow(a)
_csv.Error: sequence expected

Comment: print output copy and pasted:  Major
Critical
Critical
Critical
Critical
Critical
Major
Critical
Critical
Critical
Critical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writer.writerows()` expects an iterable, for example a list, which it can convert into a set of rows. Since this conversion requires an iterable, we're talking about something like a list of lists.
`writer.writerow()` expects an iterable, which it can convert into a row - that is, a list of values. If you want to just write this value as a single column in a one-column csv, you could do

```
writer.writerow([a])
```

But if you want it included with other data, you're going to have to produce that list of values:

```
data.append(a)
writer.writerow(data)
```

(`data` here is some existing list of values that you've already assembled)

Comment: This did put it to a csv!  I was going to append to a csv with data already in it.

Comment: To append, `with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'ab') as f:`

Comment: @Eddwinn To do that, you're going to have to ingest the existing csv and modify the data, then rewrite it to the output file.

Comment: @Jérôme - since the goal is to modify existing data, appending is probably not the right thing.

Comment: @JonKiparsky curiously, if a = "Critical" then that is actually iterable. In Py3 I don't get this error... (although I agree your answer is correct of course)

Comment: @Will Yes, "Critical" is iterable, but the failure occurs when it tries to call writerow('C') and finds that 'C' is not a sequence.

Comment: The script is pulling data from a table on the internet, and transforming it into a csv

Comment: @JonKiparsky That's what I thought, but Py3 runs no error : cvs.writer(f).writerows("Critical")